# how do I make elements align to middle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout like this

```
Title               'up icon'  
                    'down icon'
```

The up icon and down icon are both link. I need all of them to be vertical center.

Here are my html

inside a  tag.

```
 <th>
      <div>Title</div>
      <a href="#" onclick="sortup()">
            <span><img src=="up.png"/></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" onclick="sortdown()">
            <span><img src=="down.png"/></span>
      </a>
  </th>
```

currently the layout is like

```
Title     'up icon' 'down icon'
```

How do I make it to

```
Title               'up icon'  
                    'down icon'
```

Title and icons need to be vertical align to middle instead of align to top here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create a fiddle and show us what you have tried.

Comment: HTML attributes are not supposed to have double equals signs (your img src's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or just add a break in between the two links :)

```
<th>
      <div>Title</div>
      <a href="#" onclick="sortup()">
            <span><img src=="up.png"/></span>
      </a>
      <br>
      <a href="#" onclick="sortdown()">
            <span><img src=="down.png"/></span>
      </a>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<a>` elements in `divs`

```
<th>
    <div>Title</div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="sortup()">
            <span><img src="up.png" /></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="sortdown()">
            <span><img src="down.png" /></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</th>
```